# Any gradient guru can convert this to -webkit?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have this css gradient that I made for chrome:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(200,0,0,.22) 50%, transparent 50%),
linear-gradient(rgba(200,0,0,.26) 50%, transparent 50%);
background-size:50px 50px;
```

But I'm going bananas trying to port it to webkit and maybe even moz.
I tried many online tools but no luck.

Comment: Can you provide a live example of your declaration?

Comment: This link can be useful http://www.sitepoint.com/using-unprefixed-css3-gradients-in-modern-browsers/

Answer (score 1):

There's a guru for you : http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Is free

For preparing a css cascade for cross-browser, it looks this way :

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,0,0,0.22) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,0.61) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,0.62) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(200,0,0,0.22)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,0.61)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,0.62)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,0,0,0.22) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,0.61) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.62) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,0,0,0.22) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,0.61) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.62) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,0,0,0.22) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,0.61) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.62) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(200,0,0,0.22) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,0.61) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.62) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
```

Where you'll notice the double -webkit- declaration.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `90deg` in the property value. It's specifying directionality. Linear just means it's straight (not radial etc.) Specifying `90deg` is saying, "rotate gradient so it's 90 degrees from top."

Comment: @setek you're right, i mistaken myself from the way OP is written. On second part of css, the 90deg is not mentioned. Thanks, that was useful

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify directionality for `-webkit-` and `-moz-` gradients. It's not assumed.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Yh8R/

```
div { height: 100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(200,0,0,.22) 50%, transparent 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,0,0,.26) 50%, transparent 50%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(200,0,0,.22) 50%, transparent 50%), -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,0,0,.26) 50%, transparent 50%);
    /*background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(200,0,0,.22) 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(rgba(200,0,0,.26) 50%, transparent 50%);*/
    background-size:50px 50px; }
```

Just uncomment the spec version for production (was just so I could test the browser variants worked.)

Comment: awesome!I had to change background to background-image to work properly though. Thanks for taking the time to help me out guys.